# How do I troubleshoot my new graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, computer-building

I just got this [nvidia 3060 gtx](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B098682XKX) video card to replace my old ATI radeon 5870 and this [asus rampage ii extreme](https://www.asus.com/us/SupportOnly/Rampage_II_Extreme/HelpDesk_Manual/) motherboard. The motherboard is quite old and I was hoping to put in the new graphics card without rebuilding my entire rig. The graphics card does not generate any display to the monitors. Im using the hdmi ports if it matters. No output from the nvidia even on startup like the bios screen. The mobo has pcie 2.0 slots and the new card is pcie 4.0 which is supposed to be backwards compatible. Running latest windows 10 64 bit. Any idea if this should be working or what I should try?

What I tried: I flashed the bios to the admitedly very old latest (2011) version. I uninstalled my old ATI graphics driver. Right now I have both the old and new graphics cards installed so I can get some display from the ATI card. I tried installing the nvidia drivers (of course I initially tried with just the new graphics card installed and the ATI card removed but no output whatsoever). The nvidia installer is saying incompatible hardware. Maybe because I have both plugged in at the moment. The box arrived from UPS and looked like someone played soccer with it so not sure it is my older mobo or if its damaged.

Do I return the card or try building a new computer around it. I guess the 650$ gpu will end up costing me an extra 1000$ if I need a new motherboard, cpu, ram, etc.

Comment: It is not possible to install both the AMD and Nvidia drivers on the same system.  If the Nvidia card is not being detected in the Device Manager then it's incompatible with your hardware.  We will be unable to provide you our optionion if you should return the card or not.

Comment: I uninstalled the amd driver and tried to start with just the Nvidia card. It doesn't even show th post bios screen.

Comment: Yes; I suspect you have a hardware incompatibility. While PCIe is backwards compatible there are other considerations that do exist. In this case I suspect a hardware identification issue might be the cause. I think it’s a combination of either the display id, an incompatibility with your UEFI and the cards VBIOS, or your PSU isn’t compatible with your card. There is a fourth possibility the card was DOA.

Comment: Of course my theory breaks down since Display ID isn’t a thing with HDMI.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense. Was trying to avoid updating the entire system since just use it for few things but I guess its inevitable. So new mobo/cpu/ram for computer I use a few times a week. Not really a gamer any longer so seems a bit pricy for me to do some ocassional graphic design, computer programming projects, some guitar recording. The problem is I have to scramble to put together a new computer within the 30 day return policy for the GPU in case it was DOA. Would feel better if I could just confirm somehow the card works. The UPS box really did look like someone played soccer with it.

Comment: None of what I list has anything to do with gaming

Comment: True. Anyway I dropped 800$ on a new build yesterday. Gpu card is working on bios startup so I feel a bit better.  Waiting on a new DVD drive from amazon to install windows. Yeah yeah my new mobo doesnt have an eide slot. I know eide is old. In a few years we will say the same about sata. The concept of upgradability is a fallacy. The economy must thrive. Is there a stack exchange for disgruntled old dudes tired of paying for stuff we don't need that will break after a week?

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to put lipstick on a pig unfortunately. The 13 year old motherboard is worth nothing at all except maybe to run some sort of Linux in the background. Getting a modern video card to work even in the unlikely event it could be made to work would simply be downgrading a $600 video card to something you would expect to be given for nothing - like the motherboard.

If you want to get value from your video card you either put more money in to get a new motherboard etc or you return it.

I think you could probably find someone to give you a five year old motherboard that would run this card.

Since you mention Blender in a comment, take note of their hardware requirements (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) which state two things of note: 1. Hardware less than 10 years old and 2. Latest bios

If you can't find bios less than 11 years old perhaps you should give up on either Blender or your current motherboard.

Comment: My 10 year old build runs everything I need it to except blender which crashes due to performance. That's the entire reason I bought the new card. You can't just go grab a 5 year old mobo from a friend. You need a cpu minimally assuming you have a case and psu already. But you didn't really even try to answer the question did you. Everything I read says pcie4 can run on a pcie2 slot. So is the card defective or is there a technical reason it's not rowking.

Comment: *In theory* a PCIE4 card can run on a PCI2 motherboard. In practice I would be amazed if anyone could get it working. Hell I'm amazed anyone is trying. If you did manage it, as I said, you would simply have found a way to make a $600 video card perform like a $0 to $50 video card. That really should answer your question, if you feel it doesn't perhaps you are trying too hard to 'paint the pig'.

Comment: Just reiterating what a dozen forums say. Pcie is backwards and forwards compatible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: btw blender works fine with my old rig except a few things (subdivision surface modifier for instance which is pretty important). Blender logs lead me to believe its the version of opengl supported by the old card which means blender uses some methods in the newest opengl api - probably for the subdivision surface modifier. If the new card worked in my rig then blender would work fine. If I build a new computer I have to get it done within the 30 day return window for the GPU. Was hoping to not spend 1200+ to get one or 2 features of blender working. Or I just return the GPU I guess.